# C programming: How to Access a Single Character from variable Type char**

Tags: c

I have a main here for testing that passes a simple sentence as a test.

```
    int main()
{
   char *sentence = "Hello There."; /* test sentence */
   char *word;  /* pointer to a word */

  printf( "sentence = \"%s\"\n", sentence );  /* show the sentence */

  word = get_word( &sentence );  /* this will allocate memory for a word */

  printf( "word = \"%s\"; sentence = \"%s\"\n", word, sentence );  /* 
  print out to see what's happening */

  free(word);  /* free the memory that was allocated in get_word */

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my get_word function that requires a char** as a passing argument and must output a pointer.

```
char *get_word( char **string_ptr )
{
    char *word;
    word = (char*)malloc(919 * sizeof(char)); /* Assign memory space for storying gathered characters */
    strcpy(word,"")  /***********This is the line I need help with****/ 

  return word;
}
```

This is an assignment question for a school project so cant ask for too much, my main concern is i would like to figure out how i can pass the first character 'H' of the sentence within main, to the variable word within my get_word function. Since this function is part of an assignment, I cannot change the signature.

There is more to the question, like sorting between uppercase and lowercase, but i figure if i understand this concept I should be able to do the rest.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: do you know how to get a single character from a `char*` type?

Comment: Do you want to pass the single character `'H'`, or a pointer to it?  If you want to pass a single character, you need to review the signature of `strcpy()` — it would be a mistake to pass a single character as the second argument.  What do you know about dereferencing pointers?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know a little bit about dereferencing. It basically gathers a value from a pointer? if i use the code {  strcpy(word, *string_ptr); } I can pass the entire value of the sting to the variable word.

Comment: I need to be able to pass a single character, the question requires me to loop over the entire string until a non letter character is reached, convert any uppercase letters to lowercase and then return a single word. then ill have to do this again for the next set of letter characters in the sting.

Comment: Right — `strcpy(word, *string_ptr)` will copy the string `"Hello world"` into the array `word`.  And if you only want to copy one character from a string, consider `strncpy()`, but don't forget to null-terminate the result string.  It looks like you're going to need to update the value in `*string_ptr` to allow for the characters copied to the return function — that's why it needs to be a `char **` and not just a `char *`.

Comment: Life saver! @JonathanLeffler! please post an answer and i will mark it for you. I should have gotten this, it is very simple.

Comment: right. To get a single character, you'll have to dereference `char** string_ptr` twice.. first time to get the word, second time to get the character (in this example). Since you want the first character of the first word in this case, `char c = **string_ptr;` will do it, but that's a simplified case. To get other characters (or other characters in other words if they existed), you would need to perform some pointer arithmetic before dereferencing. Also take note that a C string much be at least 2 characters (terminated with NUL `'\0'`)

Comment: @TylerGee A pointer is simply a variable that holds the address of something else as its value. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate value, such as `int a = 5;`, a pointer would simply hold the address where `5` was stored, e.g. `int *b = &a;`. To get the thing stored at the address of `a` from `b`, you simply *dereference* `b` (e.g. `*b`), the `'*'` removes 1-level of address indirection, so rather than giving you what is stored in `b`, you get the thing stored at the address held by `b` (e.g. `5`). Apply that to what you are doing with `sentence`...

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but you will probably learn something from [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).  Also, note that `sizeof (char)` is always `1` (as we measure sizes in units of `char`), so it's pointless to multiply by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, I asked:

> Do you want to pass the single character `'H'`, or a pointer to it? If you want to pass a single character, you need to review the signature of `strcpy()` — it would be a mistake to pass a single character as the second argument. What do you know about dereferencing pointers?

To which the response was:

> I know a little bit about dereferencing. It basically gathers a value from a pointer? If I use the code `strcpy(word, *string_ptr);`, I can copy the entire value of the string to the variable word.
>
> I need to be able to pass a single character; the question requires me to loop over the entire string until a non-letter character is reached, convert any uppercase letters to lowercase and then return a single word. then I'll have to do this again for the next set of letter characters in the string.

And I noted:

> Right — `strcpy(word, *string_ptr)` will copy the string `"Hello world"` into the array `word`. And if you only want to copy one character from a string, consider `strncpy()`, but don't forget to null-terminate the result string. It looks like you're going to need to update the value in `*string_ptr` to allow for the characters copied to the return function — that's why it needs to be a `char **` and not just a `char *`.

However, given the requirements, it is probably better not to use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`.

You could get to the `H` using `(*string_ptr)[0]` or even `**string_ptr`, but the array notation with the pointer is rather ungainly to type out very often (more than once?).  Both of them are vulnerable to crashes if the pointer in `(*string_ptr)` is a null pointer — or otherwise invalid; however, that's also true of the code below.  You could check with `assert(*string_ptr != NULL);` if you wished, and you included `<assert.h>`, whatever other error handling you choose.

There are many options, but I'd probably use a variant on:

```
char *src = *string_ptr;   /* Starting position */
char *dst = word;
int c;

while (*src != '\0')
{
    int c = (unsigned char)*src++;
    …break on space or other characters as required…
    …map c as required…
    *dst++ = c;
}
*dst = '\0';  /* Null terminate the string */
*string_ptr = src;
return word;
```

That avoids a variety of problems.  Using the local pointer `src` (the source string — matches `dst`, the destination string) avoids having to write `(*string_ptr)` all the time.  Using `c` gets ready to pass the value to the functions (macros) from `<ctype.h>`.  The cast to `(unsigned char)` deals with
accented characters in a single-byte code set when the plain `char` type is signed (and is harmless when the plain `char` type is unsigned).  The increment in the loop avoids overshooting the end of the string.